# else if anidado en python

Tags: python, array, lista, condiciones, else

Estoy intentando crear uno arreglo que me etiquete unas imágenes que tienen en su nombre la clase a la que pertenecen pero luego de la primera condición me sigue toma la segunda y no sigue haciendo las otras clasificaciones:

código:

```
fnames_train = np.array([f'{PATH}/train/{f}' for f in (os.listdir(f'{PATH}/train'))])
labels_train = np.array([(0 if 'cloudy' in fname else 1 if 'rain' in fname else 2 if 'shine' in fname else 3 if 'sunrise' in fname else 4 )for fname in fnames_train])
```

resultado:

```
np.unique(labels_train,return_counts=True)
(array([0, 1]), array([240, 660]))
```

la clase 'cloudy' si tiene 240 imágenes pero las otras clases solo las esta clasificando como '1'

ayuda!!

Comment: Es porque la palabra "train" contiene "rain"

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.